# Where can I get Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf DVD label and DVD cover image?

Tags: dvd, community

I found [this image](http://irfree.com/applications/windows/513065-ubuntu-1510-wily-werewolf.html), but they do not have a printable version.

I searched all over the Internet and couldn't find any Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf DVD Label and DVD cover image.

I need this for our Ubuntu release party to prepare dvds.

[image: DVD case]

Comment: I don't think it's available yet? You can keep an eye out on [this page](http://spreadubuntu.neomenlo.org/en/get-materials) if you want. I think they have some tools to make your own, if you're so inclined. If you do make them, please share.

Answer (score 1):

I made one myself, with help of [this site](http://spreadubuntu.org/files/source/12.10-Quetzal.xcf)

Here is it.. sharing with love.

[image: printable version]

Can also be downloaded [here](http://spreadubuntu.org/en/material/packaging/ubuntu-1510-wily-werewolf-dvd-cover).